# Service in AngularJS works just once (after refresh)

Tags: angularjs, service

When i use the function addact() for the first time(after refresh) it works.But, in after (in the next times) it returns an empty object in the callback until i refresh.

response(first time) :

```
activité : Object {nom: "nouvelle activité", projetId: "2", id: "43", creationDate_: "03/06/2015", state_: "-1"…
```

response(after) :

```
activité :
```

---

### JS

```js
$scope.addact = function (){
        $scope.newActivite.$setPristine;
        $scope.newActivite.nom="nouvelle activité";
        $scope.newActivite.projetId=$scope.projet.id;
        addActivite($scope.newActivite);
}

function addActivite(activite) {
  activiteService.addActivite(activite).success(function (data) {
    $scope.newActivite = data;
    listActivite();
    console.log("activité: ",$scope.newActivite);
  });
}
```

### HTML

```html
<section class="activite" ng-repeat="activite in activites">

    <header class="activite-title">
        {{activite.nom}}
    </header>
    <section class="activite-body">
        <div class="action" ng-repeat="action in activite.actions"  >
            {{action.nom}}
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: where is your service function ?

Comment: `$setPristine()` is a function but you aren't invoking it

Comment: Are you sure that your backend is responding something ? You're always sending the same name/projetId.